# Get code to not return undefined after running

Tags: javascript, replit

I created a function that inserts a number into an array of integers. I am assuming that the array is always sorted already.I want it to return the lowest index where the number can be inserted. I have accomplished that but after it returns the index it also returns undefined when i run it on repl.it. Wondering why that is happening?

```js
    function lowestIndexInsert(num,arr){
      for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
          if (arr[i]>num){
             arr[i]=num;
          }
      }
     return arr.indexOf(num);
    }


    console.log(lowestIndexInsert(32,[8,9,15,30,35]));
```

Comment: the "undefined" message comes from console.log. as example console.log('test') will also show undefined

Comment: If you remove `console.log` in repl.it, and just call the function, you'll not see that `undefined` anymore, but you will see the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `console.log()` statement is part of your source code, you will just get the result you want. But, if you are actually executing the `console.log()` from a console, you will get the extra `undefined` because in a `console`, you don't have to ask for `console.log()`, which, itself has no return value (`undefined`). In that case, you would just invoke your function and let its `return` value be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```js
let arr = [1,2,32,35,56,68]
let num = 30

function lowestIndexInsert(num,arr){
  for(let i of arr){
    if(arr[i]>num)
    return i
  }
}

console.log(lowestIndexInsert(num,arr))
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all. You've re-written the loop, which wasn't the issue. This doesn't even address the question.

Answer (score 0):

the "undefined" message comes from console.log. as example console.log('test') will also show undefined.
Try wthout console.log and you are done

```
    function lowestIndexInsert(num,arr){
  for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i]>num){
         arr[i]=num;
      }
  }
 return arr.indexOf(num);
}


lowestIndexInsert(32,[8,9,15,30,35])
```